# split a console in two parts for two outputs

Tags: c#, redirect, console, io

I'm creating a console application where I would like to have two outputs and one input. The reason would be so that one output is always visible.

```
This is the first output
Text flows upwards just like a regular console application, however...

---------
This is a second output
This is placed at the bottom of the console // also input goes here.
```

I was thinking of calling it something like this

```
 Console.Out.Writeline("This is the first output");
 Console.Out.Writeline("Text flows upwards just like a regular console application, however...");
 MyTextWriter.WriteLine("This is a second output");
 MyTextWriter.WriteLine("This is placed at the bottom of the console");
```

But how would I go about splitting the console in two parts? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use Console.SetCursorPosition to draw text where you want it. Here's a crude example that split the console in two areas with text flowing upward when added to them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> area1 = new List<string>();
        static List<string> area2 = new List<string>();
        static int areaHeights = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Number of rows for each area
            areaHeights = (Console.WindowHeight - 2) / 2;

            drawScreen();

            int i = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                i++;

                // jumb between areas
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    AddLineToBuffer(ref area1, Console.ReadLine());
                else
                    AddLineToBuffer(ref area2, Console.ReadLine());

                drawScreen();
            }
        }

        private static void AddLineToBuffer(ref List<string> areaBuffer, string line)
        {
            areaBuffer.Insert(0, line);

            if (areaBuffer.Count == areaHeights)
            {
                areaBuffer.RemoveAt(areaHeights - 1);
            }
        }


        private static void drawScreen()
        {
            Console.Clear();

            // Draw the area divider
            for (int i = 0; i < Console.BufferWidth; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, areaHeights);
                Console.Write('=');
            }

            int currentLine = areaHeights - 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < area1.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLine - (i + 1));
                Console.WriteLine(area1[i]);

            }

            currentLine = (areaHeights * 2);
            for(int i = 0; i < area2.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLine - (i + 1));
                Console.WriteLine(area2[i]);
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.WindowHeight - 1);
            Console.Write("> ");

        }

    }
}
```

I assume you want to fill each area not only with user input? If so you need to set up the drawing of the console in a separate thread and let that thread update the screen when needed.

Comment: That's really neat! This is really the format I am looking for :) Although, the issue is, I already have a lot of code which uses Console.Out to write, so I would need to somehow redirect the output and manually output it like this. Needs some tinkering :) +1 though

Comment: That works great! Something to take note of though - if you are doing a lot of writing to the console the Console.Clear() causes flickering.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand you correctly, this may help:

```
Console.WriteLine("Head");
Console.WriteLine("Message");
Console.ReadKey();
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Message2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unique idea, but so far I have not noticed something similar by using a plain console application.

So what's stopping you from using a form application and divide the program into 2 different parts?

Another way you might want to try is to output into 2 different console, which most probably you do not want.

Comment: A form application is not always possible, if you think about ssh/putty for instance. (Fine, you can X11 forward and stuff, but *sometimes* only a prompt is provided at a server and nothing else)

Answer (score -1):

The standard Windows console does not provide any functionality of this kind. You will have to write your own kind of window that does this.